# Breadcrumb with taxonomy path

Tags: 7, theming, nodes, taxonomy-terms

*I use the theme "Bootstrap".*

When I display a node, there is no breadcrumb. My nodes are related to taxonomy terms.

On the screenshots :

> Boutique / Les chocolats BIO

The second screenshot should be :

> Boutique / Les chocolats BIO / Tablette de chocolat noir artisanale
>   BIO aux épices tchaï

"Boutique" is the vocabulary of taxonomy and "Les chocolats BIO" is the terms of taxonomy.

How to display the breadcrumb on the nodes without using any additional modules ?

[image]

[image]

Comment: @Wim Mostrey Make a customized module. Does not work with template.php ?

Comment: I updated my question

Comment: @Wim Mostrey How do I do this with template.php? Can you make an answer? Thank you

Comment: @Wim Mostrey Thank you. How to call "theme_breadcrumb()" ? Can put an answer ?

Comment: Generally you wouldn't do this in the theme. If the breadcrumbs were already there and you wanted to change their display in some way it would go there, however you are actually setting the breadcrumbs themselves, which should be done in a custom module using drupal_set_breadcrumb(). - Or with an already available module, for example https://www.drupal.org/project/path_breadcrumbs

Comment: I found the module I needed "Crumbs"

Answer (score 1):

you can implement hook_node_view and make alterations in the breadcrump
eg:

```
/*
 * Implements hook_node_view().
 */
function my_custom_module_node_view($node, $view_mode) {
  if ($node->type == 'my-node-type') {
    $type == $node->field_test_field['und'][0]['value'];
    if ($type == 0) {
      $breadcrumb = drupal_get_breadcrumb();
      $breadcrumb[1] = 'new breadcrumb';
      drupal_set_breadcrumb($breadcrumb);
    }
  }
}
```